# IE compatibility Changing is not working in Windows10 using meta tag

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, meta-tags, windows-10

I have created an ASP.net web application, in this we are changing the browser compatibility to IE 5 using the meta tag.

In windows7 and Windows8 there is no problem with browser compatibility, but in windows 10 beta version the browser compatibility version cannot change using these.

How can I get browser compatibility to IE 5 in windows10 ?

Did I miss some thing??

Answer (score 1):

**Old Browser Strategy**

In the now outdated IE blog post, [Living on the Edge](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/11/living-on-the-edge-our-next-step-in-interoperability.aspx), Windows 10 was intended to only support the compatibility document modes in a few scenarios:

1. if the website is on an intranet,
2. if Internet Explorer is operating in Enterprise mode.

Otherwise IE would only use the latest operating mode and ignore the X-UA-Compatible tags.

**New Browser Strategy**

Microsoft recently changed this strategy.  According to a newer post, [Updates from the "Project Spartan" Developer Workshop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/03/24/updates-from-the-project-spartan-developer-workshop.aspx), IE in Windows 10 will retain all functionality from Windows 8.1. That is, it will retain all of the old document modes. Note that the new browser, Edge (code-name Project Spartan), will not support the old document modes.

**Your problem/ Solution**

It is likely that the version of Windows 10 that you are testing with has implemented the older browser strategy from above. According to the second link above, the new browser strategy will be introduced in a "later" Windows 10 release. The post is dated March of this year, so it is possible that the release is already out.

I would do the following to see if they resolve your issue:

1. Update to the latest Windows 10 beta - make sure you are on the fast track for updates.
2. Make sure you are testing with Internet Explorer, and not Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Add the website to compatibility view of IE